# Using a try-catch to display an image in a new browser window C#

Tags: c#, .net, uri, try-catch, webclient

Using .net and C#

My previous question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238973/error-uri-formats-are-not-supported-how-to-pull-image-off-web)

In my previous question I was trying to pull an image from a folder. I have changed my code from suggestions to dynamically pull images from my company webpage.

There is code before this code that parses the products ID for use in this piece of code.

This code is suppose to:

- Path to company website url up to /XL/
- Take the parses product ID and add XL.jpg to the end (example: productXL.jpg)
- Open the image in a new window

  ```
  protected void OpenImg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string PathToImage = "http://www.companysite.com/img/XL/";
      var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(PathToImage);
      string FileName = Variables.param + "XL.jpg";
      var foundFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles(FileName);


      try
      {
          WebClient wc = new WebClient();
          wc.UploadFile(PathToImage, FileName);

          int i = 0;

          ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "openFoundImage", "window.open('" + PathToImage + foundFiles[i].Name + "');", true);
      }
      catch
      {
      }
  }
  ```

I'm getting a web error "URI formats are not supported." when I open up the page. I've never written a try-catch code and I'm rather new to C# as well so if I'm doing this all wrong please explain. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To open that image in internet explorer:

```
Process.Start("iexplore.exe", @"http://www.companysite.com/img/XL/");
```

You can have it open in any browser that is installed by changing the first parameter to the name of the executable of browser you want to use, for example, chrome would be "chrome.exe"